# Subscribe fires twice

Tags: angular, service

I try to communicate between two component one which is dialog.component.ts and the other admin.component.ts with a service between them.

So in my dialog i have a form which triggered the service with the ngsubmit

```
collectSubmitForm(any) {
    var myObj= new Object({form: any,typeOfForm: this.data.titleDialog});
    this.dialogContentService.getCollectFormContent(myObj);
  }
```

In my dialogService i have :

```
  private dialogFormContent = new Subject<any>();

  dialogFormContentUpdate$ = this.dialogFormContent.asObservable();

  constructor() {

  }

  getCollectFormContent(dataAsParams) {
    this.dialogFormContent.next(dataAsParams);
    this.dialogFormContent = new Subject<any>();
  }
```

and in my admin.component.ts i have :
//Todo a revoir 2 call

```
 constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) {
    this.collectDataFromDialog();
  }
  collectDataFromDialog() {
    this.subscription = this.dialogService.dialogFormContentUpdate$.subscribe(valueFromFormDialog => {
      if(valueFromFormDialog){
        this.subscriptionValueFromDialog = valueFromFormDialog;
        this.anOtherFunction(this.subscriptionValueFromDialog)
      }
    });
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

I don't know why the subscription is call two times

Comment: it's because of your new assignation inside getCollectFormContent(), remove it or for a fast solution just add pipe(take(1)) in your subscription: this.dialogService.dialogFormContentUpdate$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...)

Comment: I try with and without same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

good morning :D

Probably is this part of code

```js
  getCollectFormContent(dataAsParams) {
    this.dialogFormContent.next(dataAsParams);
    this.dialogFormContent = new Subject<any>();
  }
```

I think that you need to remove the new Subject() like this:

```html
  getCollectFormContent(dataAsParams) {
    this.dialogFormContent.next(dataAsParams);
  }
```

Try it :D

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution to make data binding between a component and another component in the dialog I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67267263/12834967).